# How to save the dynamic generate PDF file in CI those generate by DOMPDF library in CI

Tags: codeigniter

How to save the PDF file in particular folder those generate by click on button button and its generated dynamically in Ci with the use of DOMPDF library in CI... Actually my problem only raise the file the generate successfully but i not able to stored the file in the particular folder .. pls tell me how to do save the file in particular folder.?

```
<?php

$html = "<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th><th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yssyogesh</td>
            <td>yssyogesh@makitweb.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sonarika</td>
            <td>sonarika@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>vishal</td>
            <td>vishal@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        </table>";
 $output = '<table width="100%" style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;">';
 $output .='<tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">
                   <td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" colspan="2"> Smart Citizen</td>
                   </tr>';
  foreach($update_data->result() as $row)
  {

   $output .= '

                    <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;" > Fullfilment Id </td>
                    <td style=" border: 1px solid black;
                   border-collapse: collapse;" >'.strtoupper(substr($row->department_name,0,2)).$row->redeem_id.'</td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;" > 
                     <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;"> Department Name </td>
                     <td style=" border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;">'.$row->department_name.'</td>
                    </tr>  

                     <tr  style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                      border-collapse: collapse;"> 
                    <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;" > Department Mobile Number </td>
                    <td   style=" border: 1px solid black;
                      border-collapse: collapse;">'.$row->cordinators_mobileno.'</td>
                    </tr> 

                    <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                   border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                 border-collapse: collapse;" >Reward Name </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;
               border-collapse: collapse;">'.$row->reward_name.'</td>
                    </tr> 

                    <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;" >Reward Point </td>
                    <td  style=" border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">'.$row->r_point.'</td> 
                     </tr>

                  <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;" >Estimate Time </td>
                    <td  style=" border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;">'.$row->estimate_time.'</td> 
                     </tr>
   ';

  }
  $output .= '

  ';
  $output .= '</table>';


$filename = "Smart_Citizen";

// include autoloader
require_once APPPATH.'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($output);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream($filename);

$file_to_save = APPPATH. "dompdf/";
file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output());






the file save in folder dompdf particlar
```

Comment: $file_to_save is just a path. Don't you need to add the actual filename as well?

Comment: i not able too understand what u say?

Comment: file is not stored . in folder

Comment: In your example, $file_to_save is NOT a filename. It is a PATH to a FOLDER Only. APPPATH.'dompdf/' should be APPPATH.'dompdf/'. $filename.'.pdf' or something like that.